# powershell convert to html ,facing line formatting issues

Tags: html, powershell

Recently I have developed a code to read data from files, format it and write to html. Though I am able to write to the html I am facing formatting issues and all the data is coming as a single paragraph without any line breaks. I have tried so many ways. i am very new to powershell

```html
$a = Get-Date

$fxtDelimiter="----------------------------FXT Daily Status--------------------------------------------"
$fxtData=(Get-Content -tail 2 G:\EmailActivity\Logs\FXTRekon.log) -split ': '
$fxtDownloaded="No of fxt files downloaded for the day"
$fxtFilesDownloaded="$($fxtDownloaded): $($a.ToShortDateString())- $($fxtData[2])"

$symphonyDelimiter="----------------------------Symphony Daily Status--------------------------------------------"

$symphonyData=(Get-Content -tail 5 G:\EmailActivity\Logs\SymphonyRekon.log) -split ': '
$symphonyZipFilesDownloaded="No of symphony zip files downloaded for the day"
$symphonyZipsDownloaded="$($symphonyZipFilesDownloaded): $($a.ToShortDateString())- $($symphonyData[2])"
$symphonySourceFilesProcessed="No of symphony files processed for the day"
$symphonyFilesProcessed="$($symphonySourceFilesProcessed): $($a.ToShortDateString())- $($symphonyData[5])"

$MailBody =  $fxtDelimiter+"`n"+$fxtFilesDownloaded +"`n" + "`n" +$symphonyDelimiter+ "`n" +"`n" +$symphonyZipsDownloaded + "`n"+$symphonyFilesProcessed

ConvertTo-Html -Title "DailyStatus" -Body "<center><H2><u> Daily Feeds Report</u></H2></center>"  -PostContent $MailBody > G:\EmailActivity\Test.htm
 
Invoke-Expression G:\EmailActivity\Test.htm
```

The output i am getting as single paragraph without any line breaks, tough i have kept it in `$MailBody`

> Daily Feeds Report----------------------------FXT Daily
>   Status-------------------------------------------- No of fxt files
>   downloaded for the day: 11/27/2017- 514
>   ----------------------------Symphony Daily Status-------------------------------------------- No of symphony zip
>   files downloaded for the day: 11/27/2017- 1 No of symphony files
>   processed for the day: 11/27/2017- 6

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk more of HTML than PowerShell, HTML doesn't recognise newline chars as you would expect so you end up with everything on one line.

For a quick fix just use `"<br>"` instead:

```
$MailBody =  $fxtDelimiter+"<br>"+$fxtFilesDownloaded +"<br>" + "<br>" +$symphonyDelimiter+ "<br>" +"<br>" +$symphonyZipsDownloaded + "<br>"+$symphonyFilesProcessed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `n to each variable so it would look like

```
$fxtDelimiter="------------------FXT Daily Status------------------------------`n"
$fxtDownloaded="No of fxt files downloaded for the day`n"
$fxtFilesDownloaded="$($fxtDownloaded): $($a.ToShortDateString())- $($fxtData[2]) `n"
```

and so on and so forth...

Comment: Hi ShanayL its still giving the same output